# Space Divs horizontally and vertically in a centred wrap

Tags: css, centering, spacing

I'm looking to create something like the image shown:

[image]

I have managed to get the #wrap centred horizontally, but that's about it...
any help would be much appreciated.

```
<style>
    #wrap
    {
    Margin-left:auto;
    Margin-right:auto;
    padding: 10px;
    }

    #content
    {
    padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

~~~

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap">

       <div id="content">
       1
       </div>
       <div id="content">
       2
       </div>
       <div id="content">
       3
       </div>

    </div> <!--end wrap-->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're working with block elements (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements) you need the inner elment to have a fixed height so that you can give `position: absolute`. Additionally, keep in mind that the ID of an element has to be unique. If you want to use an element mulitple times assign a `class` name, e.g.

```
<div class="content">1</div>
<div class="content">2</div>
<div class="content">3</div>
```

So, for the whole matter have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/YFncP/253/

Hope this helps.